# Creating a physical folder on WordPress with the same name as a post_type, for .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

A WordPress installation I am currently setting up has a `post_type` called Services, which resides at `/services/`.

This is a relaunch of an existing website on an archaic CMS, so a lot of old pages need redirecting. I need to manually redirect a large number of URLs from the old site to the new site. I want to include a separate `.htaccess` file within `/services/` to contain all of the 301s for this directory.

However, as soon as I create a physical `/services/` directory on my server, it stops WordPress from working and tries to load the non-existent physical index file instead. Is there a way to create physical folders on my server for `.htaccess` purposes, but still have the request handled by WordPress if none of the 301 redirect requests are fulfilled?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the Redirection plugin. While not quite what you're after, if you're able to get a CSV/XML list of redirects, you can bulk add them. http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: The problem is, I literally have thousands of redirects to put in place, which is why I wanted to separate them out into a multitude of .htaccess files in separate directories.


Unfortunately it'd be really difficult to create regexes which would match the old URLs to WordPress slugs.


I'm guessing using the Redirection plugin for this many URLs would create a big performance issue?

Comment: Maybe, haven't tested it with more than a few hundred. Try changing your permalinks to without a trailing slash? That *used* to work under very particular circumstances.